# asp.net mvc 3, need help to map the route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, routes

here's the URL I want to map, http://localhost/tool/votetool/123/up

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{toolId}/{vote}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Tool", action = "VoteTool", toolId = UrlParameter.Optional, vote = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { vote = "up|down"}
        );
```

in my page I use html.actionlink to generate the URL.

```
@Html.ActionLink("ThumbUp", "VoteTool", "Tool", new { toolId = Model.Tool.Id, vote = "up" })
```

Instead getting an URL similar to this one : http://localhost/tool/votetool/123/up

here's the URL I am getting:

http://localhost:60627/Tool/VoteTool?Length=4

why am I getting length=4 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `(linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes)` overload of `ActionLink`.

Therefore, it treats `"Tool"` as a set of route parameters and reads the only property of the `String` class (`Length`).